# How to call same function multiple times?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, pycord

Got an async method below, which works perfectly fine when you call it once, but it throws an exception when i try to call it 2 times(on 2 servers at the same time for example). How to make it work in parallel?

**The code**:

```
@commands.slash_command(name='demotivate')
    async def demotivate(self, ctx):
        modal = MyModal()
        channel = ctx.channel
        await ctx.interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
        while True:
            while True:
                msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30)

                if msg.author == ctx.author:
                    break
                else:
                    pass
            cnt = msg.content
            if check(cnt):
                tenor_parser(cnt)
                break
            elif not check(cnt):
                free_link_downloader(cnt)
                break
            else:
                pass
        demotivate_gif(modal.upper_text, modal.lower_text, 'gifka.gif')#function that processes gif 
        #frame by frame. Here comes the problem i guess 
        #bc without this method it works fine with two or more requests at the same time
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('out.gif'))
```

I tried using multithreading, multiprocessing, asyncio packages and connecting them(blindly). I came to conclusion that the program either send wrong arguments to the demotivate_gif method, or completely ignore the second call of the function. I need help, i will very much appreciate it.

Comment: It would help us if you could copy/paste the exception

Comment: It throws Bad request exception, or ignore all the calls, or ignore one of them, OR mix them up. No clue what this all depend on.

Comment: Why is the function indented after the decorator?

Comment: it doesnt, probably missclicked